# Non-proper orthant automorphisms

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, convex-geometry, positivity, cones

Given a real vector space $V$ of dimension $d$, it is known that the automorphism Lie group of the nonnegative orthant $\mathcal{O}^+_d$ can be described just as $$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{O}^+_d)=\lbrace M\in \mathrm{GL}(V)\mid M=\mathrm{diag}(a,\dots,b), a,\dots,b\geq 0 \rbrace. $$
I'm wondering now about the automorphism group for the nonnegative orthant $\mathcal{O}^+_n$ with $n<d$. It is not a proper cone so the usual techniques for calculating the automorphism group do not apply. At the level of the Lie algebra something can be said?

Comment: Automorphism group refers to some structure: what structure do you have in mind? Also, "the non-negative orthant" depends on a basis: without a fixed basis it doesn't make sense — similarly, the notion of diagonal matrix makes sense only if you fix a basis.

Comment: @YCor Yes, naturally everything is written given a fixed basis from the beginning. And with automorphism I just mean a bijective function.

Comment: You certainly mean something else. There's no point to define the cone if you want to consider the whole permutation group. I even doubt that you want to consider the whole self-homeomorphism group, since the closed cone is just homeomorphic to a closed half-space in $\mathbf{R}^d$.

Comment: @YCor don't understand very well what you are saying with considering the whole permutation group. In the similar way as the case presented I'm just interested in how to define a Lie group (or the associated Lie algebra) of bijective maps from a face of the nonnegative orthant to itself.

Comment: I'm unfortunately unable to guess which group you have in mind. I guess you endow the orthant ($(\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0})^d$) with some structure and consider its automorphism group, but I don't guess which structure you have in mind, and thus, which group you have in mind. For instance, the affine automorphism group is reduced to the group of monomial matrices (semidirect product of the positive diagonal matrices, with the symmetric group $S_d$ permuting the coordinates).

Comment: @YCor in the question I described just the identity component of the group you mention. What I'm wondering is about the same type of group but for one face of the orthant, let's say if the space is dimension 3 I want only the two first components (for instance) of the vector to stay nonnegative and not caring about the third component.

Comment: @NicolasMedinaSanchez I don't know that I would call this an "automorphism group" because it depends on the ambient space but I believe all you are looking for then is the block triangular matrix which is a positive diagonal matrix (or product of this with $S_n$) on the span of the $n$ elements and any matrix in $GL(d-n)$ as the other diagonal block and any matrix at all in the $(n-d)\times n$ slot.

Comment: I mean $n \times (n-d)$. More invariantly the maps from our $(n-d)$-dimensional complement to the $n$ dimensional span of the orthant.